# variables cannot find the Main Driver class when it is referenced

Tags: java, static, reference, instance-variables

Im having issues now with static and non staic errors. with sertain variables unable to find the main method.

I have strated the program by creating a seperate file which instantiates the class. like so:

```
public class StartUp {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        MainDriver theMainDriver = new MainDriver();
        theMainDriver.start();
    }
}
```

Within certain classes in the program it passes variables back to the mainDriver. But when I try to refrence it to, I get the error "cannot find symbol variable theMainDriver" .

e.g:

```
 public void getEmployee()  {
      theMainDriver.setEmployee(theEmployee);
 }

 public void getEmployeeID() {
     theMainDriver.setEmployeeID( randomIDno);
 }
```

how can I declare the main Driver in a way that makes it more visible to other classes.
It does find the main driver if I do this MainDriver.setEmployeeID( randomIDno); but then it  has issues with non static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
public class StartUp {

    public static MainDriver theMainDriver;

    public void main(String[] args) {
        theMainDriver = new MainDriver();
        theMainDriver.start();
    }
}
```

And call from any class as follows:

```
Startup.theMainDriver.setEmployeeID(randomIDno);
```

Comment: the last line hmm that look hopeful I will give it a try

Comment: I am declaring the attribute theMainDriver as static and public, this enable to access to the attribute from envery class in the JVM

Comment: DUDE.! If one can access `Startup.theMainDriver.setEmployeeID(randomIDno);` they can VERY WELL access `new MainDriver().setEmployeeId(randomIDno)` [because the OP said they are in the same package and it is public.. ]

Comment: In your example you are creating another instance of the object MainDriver

Answer (score 0):

3 things if there was a compilation error.

1) Is MainDriver Public?
2) if MainDriver is in different package, did u `import` it ?
3) If MainDriver is from diffrent pacakage or different project or a external jar, Did u give that in the classpath ?

also, as the othe guy said, u for got the `static` part of the `main(String[] args)`

Comment: yes it is declared as public class MainDriver
. It is in the same package

Comment: Okay so I added the static and it kind of runs and the errors up

Comment: exception in thread awt incompatible class change error expected static method
at this code:     StartUp.theMainDriver.setDepartmentToSystem(newDepartment); 
or if I change it to this
    theMainDriver.setDepartmentToSystem(newDepartment);

Comment: if the declaration of the menthod is like this,   `void setDepartmentToSytem( XXX variabl ) {} ` .. make sure  `newDepartment` is the object of `XXX` class or any of the child class of `XXX`

Comment: never mind I herby give up on this program i shall move on to something else 
thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the declaration of main should be like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I cant understand how you are running the programm without making it static

Secondly, You didn.t gave the structure of your MainDriver class. May be it is not public. So make your MainDriver class public. I think that will resolve the problem